# Most optimized way to merge figures from multiple PDFs into one PDF page?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, reportlab, pypdf

I'm the developer of NLS GNSS SOFAMESA (https://github.com/nlsfi/nls-gnss-sofamesa) and releasing a new version of it this week. There are many updates coming. However, I haven't figured out, what is the most optimized way to merge figures from multiple pdfs into one pdf page. I have utilized reportlab and pypdf2 libraries to produce the pdfs.

**First pdf file:** 18 figures on separate pages. Total 18 pages.

**Second pdf file:** 18 figures on separate pages. Total 18 pages.

**Combined pdf file:** 36 figures so that the first figure from the first pdf file matches with the first figure from the second pdf file. Thus, two figures per page. Total 18 pages.

Later on there should be maximum 5 figures per page from five different pdfs. ^ the two pdf file example is just an example.

**Option 1:** If the "Combined pdf file" can be produced by the help of merging the existing first and second pdf files, this would be the fastest way.

**Option 2:** The figures are saved to a specific folder location, so I could just make a new pdf from the figure locations. Not the fastest way.

Example, in merger1 "...Combined_Measurement_Report_plain.pdf" is uncorrectly created containing the figures:

```py
def merger1(output_path, input_paths):
    pdf_merger = PdfFileMerger()

    for path in input_paths:
        pdf_merger.merge(position = 1, fileobj = path, pages = (5, 22))

    with open(output_path, 'wb') as fileobj:
        pdf_merger.write(fileobj)

    output_path = [output_path]
    return output_path

output_filepaths = merger1('{0}{3}{1}_{2}_Combined_Measurement_Report_plain.pdf'.format(number_of_visit_at_the_reference_point_folder_path, name_of_the_reference_point_folder, number_of_visit_at_the_reference_point, os.sep), filepaths)
```

**As previously described, I expect:**

**Combined pdf file:** 36 figures so that the first figure from the first pdf file matches with the first figure from the second pdf file. Thus, two figures per page. Total 18 pages.

Later on there should be maximum 5 figures per page from five different pdfs. ^ the two pdf file example is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PyPDF2 or [pdfrw](https://github.com/pmaupin/pdfrw) for this sort of thing. I would actually recommend pdfrw because you can specify a rectangle within the PDF to work with. It also has support for XObjects.

There are lots of examples on [Github](https://github.com/pmaupin/pdfrw) and the author is pretty responsive to questions as well.

Since I don't have access to the files in question, I can only guess at the answer. However my guess is that you will need to put together a mapping of the coordinates for the pieces you want to extract to the PDF file paths (i.e. a dict). Then iterate over your dictionary and extract the bits you want, writing them out to a new file as you go.

Comment: Thanks Mike for you response. Behind the link (Cell 13) you can find what I did. I didn't merge the existing pdfs, but utilized the existing figures and thus the ^ "**Option 2:** The figures are saved to a specific folder location, so I could just make a new pdf from the figure locations. Not the fastest way." Thanks in any case. :) https://github.com/nlsfi/nls-gnss-sofamesa/blob/master/NLS_GNSS_SOFAMESA_Main_Program.ipynb